# ASP.NET MVC Routing 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

First I want to show code

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubCategory",
            url: "Category/{categoryName}/{subName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Categories", action = "SubCategory", categoryName = "", subName = "" }
        );
```

this is my route
categoryName and subName are variables

```
// GET: Category/{categoryName}/{subName}
    public ActionResult SubCategory(string categoryName, string subName)
    {
        CategoriesViewResult viewResult = new CategoriesViewResult();
        viewResult.Categories = _db.Categories.ToList();
        viewResult.CurrentSubCategory = _db.SubCategories.First(x => x.Category.CategoryName == categoryName && x.SubCategoryName == subName);

        return View(viewResult);
    }
```

this is my method;
but I get 404.
how should i write my routes.

**UPDATE**

this is above default route.

Comment: Order matters in route.config.  Is this above or below the default route?

Comment: Is that method in `CategoriesController`?

Comment: sure in CategoriesController

Comment: What URL are you using?  Most likely, since you aren't using `UrlParameter.Optional`, your url is literally missing the values for `{categoryName}` and `{subName}`.

Comment: This code looks fine to me it should work for `yourSite/Category/books/drama`

Comment: If you enter `/Category/abc/xyz` in the address bar it will hit that method. How are you generating your link?

Comment: sure I know how i need use link

Comment: its like `/Category/abc/xyz` this

Comment: Please post your entire routing configuration including any Area routes. Most likely another route is matching before this one is able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SubCategory",
            "Category/Sub/{categoryName}/{subName}",
            new { controller = "Categories", action = "SubCategory", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional  }
        );
```

Also, which version of MVC are you using?